# Checking if selected features are adjacent using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, merge, adjacency

I need to be able to merge features on the condition that the selected features are adjacent to each other.

How can I achieve this using Open Layers version 5?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'adjecent'? Whate have you tried till now?

Comment: @TomazicM I've just done research haven't tried anything yet. And by adjacent I mean as "having a common vertex and a common side."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `turf.js#intersect` method you can find out if two features share a border.

from their docs:

> Takes two polygons and finds their intersection. If they share a border, returns the border; if they don't intersect, returns undefined.

Using this, you can convert open layer features to `turf.js#polygon`and feed them to the `intersect` method. If the return value is not `null`, the items are adjacent (share a border) or intersect.

However this will not distinguish between whether they intersect or just share a border.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the geometries on front end using openlayers and then write a postgres query to check if they intersect with each other by using ST_Intersects and apply ST_UNION if the intersects is true. This works if the backend is postgres. If you use any other DB, use appropriate spatial queries and return the result to front-end for providing appropriate user information

Comment: Ok cool, I think that's the right direction. For adjacent features you would probably use ST_Touches instead. (I previously didn't know about these methods so thank you). I'm still wondering how you'd achieve this completely client side

Comment: You might be able to use turf.js client side.  Touching features should return a result for `intersect` but the `area` of the result would be zero.